# expression function used in ggpubr::ggarrange

Tags: r, ggpubr

This is my code. The object `fig` was a list with three ggplot outcomes.

```
mylabel <- expression("PM"[2.5], "SO"[2], "O"[3])
ggpubr::ggarrange(fig[[1]], fig[[2]], fig[[3]], ncol=1, nrow=3, labels = mylabel)
```

However, I got error like this:

Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class ""expression"" to a data.frame

Does anyone know the reason? Is this my programming mistake? OR `expression` function just could not be used in `ggpubr::ggarrange` function? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think your intuition is correct, `expression` can not be used with `ggplot2`. What's the point of using `expression`? To subscript the `2` because `SO2` is Sulfur dioxide? If so, you should be able to replace `expression` with `bquote`.

Comment: @Amar's comment isn't quite correct. There are provisions in ggplot2 functions for expressions. Functions will sometimes have options to set parse=TRUE or there can be special functions typically ending in "_" that are designed to (properly?) handle standard evaluation. That said, I've looked at `ggarrange` and some of its helper functions and I don't see such provisions being supported.